# MySql FULLTEXT INDEX with JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, full-text-indexing

Is it possible to create a fulltext index on two columns derived from the inner-join of two tables? If yes, Please give me the syntax with an example.

Suppose

```
`table1 = Car_first (Columns: car_id, car_name)` 

`table2 = Car_second (Columns: car_id, car_description)`
```

Now I want to `MATCH (car_name, car_description) AGAINST` query string.
Please help. TY. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but MySQL's relevance scoring is additive so the result would be the same as having separate `FULLTEXT` indexes on the columns in each table and doing:

```
MATCH(car_name) AGAINST 'foo' + MATCH(car_description) AGAINST 'foo'
```

Comment: I am not asking about how to select data. I am asking how to add such an index..
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `idx_name` ON ....

Comment: @Adi: as my answer says, there's no way to do that directly but "*the result would be the same as having separate `FULLTEXT` indexes on the columns in each table*".

Comment: Allryt.. Thank you. But the efficiency of paired index cannot be same as that of individual indexes. I think I'll go for some schema changes. Thankx for the info. :)